# Digital TV LInux DVB-t

Tags: dvb-t

I am having a `AF9015 DVB-T USB2.0` and I don't know how to use it to watch Digital TV on my Ubuntu 14.04. I have downloaded `dvb-usb-af9015.fw` and copied it to `/lib/firmware` folder and installed `MeTV` also and rebooted.

I don't think it sees my dongle because after the scan there is no activity and no channels turn up on the scan. Running `w_scan` will give this error:

`user@E1-510:~$ w_scan -c GB -X channels.conf`

```
w_scan version 20130331 (compiled for DVB API 5.10)
using settings for UNITED KINGDOM
DVB aerial
DVB-T GB
scan type TERRESTRIAL, channellist 6
output format czap/tzap/szap/xine
WARNING: could not guess your codepage. Falling back to 'UTF-8'
output charset 'UTF-8', use -C <charset> to override
Info: using DVB adapter auto detection.
main:3228: FATAL: ***** NO USEABLE TERRESTRIAL CARD FOUND. *****
Please check wether dvb driver is loaded and
verify that no dvb application (i.e. vdr) is running.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will be helpful:

If you run me-tv and close the window using the close button, me-tv still runs. You have to close it using the menu File->Quit.

dvb-usb-af9015.fw is provided by linux-firmware-nonfree

I've never managed to detect channels without a decent antenna, event though I live in a place with no obstacles between me and the tower.